# Swift - Type 'int' does not conform to protocol 'intervaltype'

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I found the following tutorial, which suggests the code after it should work. However, both cases throw **type 'int' does not conform to protocol 'intervaltype'** errors

Swift switch tutorial: http://www.codingexplorer.com/loops-switch-statements-ranges-swift/

```
let arrayCount = someArray?.count

switch arrayCount
{
case 0:
    println("zero")
case 1:
    println("one")
default:
    println("etc")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array is declared as an optional so its count is of type `Optional(Int)`.  It's necessary to check whether `someArray` is `nil` before using the count in a `switch` statement.  Here is one way:

```
if let arrayCount = someArray?.count {
    switch arrayCount {
        case 0:
            println("zero")
        case 1:
            println("one")
        default:
            println("etc")
    }
}
```

If the array isn't `nil` the assignment will succeed and the `if` block will execute.

If you're *certain* the array isn't `nil` you can unwrap the optional using `let arrayCount = someArray!.count` instead of the conditional assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let arrayCount:Int = someArray?.count as Int

switch arrayCount
{
   case 0:
   println("zero")
case 1:
    println("one")
 default:
    println("etc")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that arrayCount is of type Int?, so you should either implicitly unwrap it when you use switch on it:

```
switch arrayCount! { }
```

which is bad in case arrayCount is  nil. Another option is that you could make sure arrayCount has a value by using coalescing operator, like this:

```
let arrayCount: Int = someArray?.count ?? 0
```

which would work in your code the way you tried to use it and also make sense for arrayCount to be 0.